# Workflow for Tailwind CSS in JIT mode

Tags: css, tailwind-css, blazor-webassembly, jit, hot-reload

I am trying out Tailwind CSS in my Blazor WASM project.

Today I use Bootstrap 5 and my workflow is to make the html structure, - run the program and make it it look nice in the browser. Adding bootstrap classes to the html.

Now I want to switch to Tailwind CSS.
I am using the following command to make Tailwind

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch
```

When using hot reload or VS Code live server they detect a change in the razor file and reload and at the same time Tailwind generate a new css file.
Sometimes Tailwind is faster, but most of the time live server / hot reload wins and I don't see the changes.

How can I make the hot reload / live server run after the tailwind update?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is possible if you do the hot reloading via VSCode. The thing is that those two processes are not linked. You can setup hotreloading via NPM / Yarn usually. Then it has a flow and will execute in the correct order.

One solution could be to only look for changes in the compiled CSS file. Then you could do it via VSCode hotreload.